# Equivalence of <limits> and <climits>

Tags: c++, c, stl, standards, limits

1. Is this guaranteed to be always true:

   ```
   std::numeric_limits<int>::max() == INT_MAX
   ```

   What does C++ standard say about it? I could not find any reference in the standard that would explicitly state this, but I keep reading that those should be equivalent.
2. What about C99 types that are not in C++98 standard for compilers that implement both C99 (at least `long long` part) and C++98? I am not sure whether there is any guarantee that this always holds true:

   ```
   std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() == ULLONG_MAX
   ```

   Is this a reasonable assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My copy of the C++ 2003 standard says that the `numeric_limits<>::max()` and `min()` templates will return values:

> Equivalent to `CHAR_MIN, SHRT_MIN, FLT_MIN, DBL_MIN,` etc.
>
> Equivalent to `CHAR_MAX, SHRT_MAX, FLT_MAX, DBL_MAX,` etc

However, those are in footnotes. ISO/IEC Directives Part 3: "[Footnotes] shall not contain requirements." Though footnotes to tables or figures may be requirements.

Comment: To be pedantic, footnotes are not part of the standard.

Comment: @dirkgently - You're right (though this is a pain to find). It's in ISO/IEC Directives Part 3: "[Footnotes] shall not contain requirements."  Though footnotes to tables or figures may be requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be the only place in the standard mentioning this.

Answer (score 2):

The first should be guaranteed to be true: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() == INT_MAX`.

However, for unsigned long long, there are no guarantees since the compiler/libraries are not required to support them. But...

If your compiler and libs support unsigned long long, it should be equal since the limits for the types will be the same regardless of how you ask.

yes, it is this a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There are obviously no guarantees for long long datatypes in C++, since long long datatypes do not yet exist in C++. How they behave, if and when they exist, is up to the compiler, and should be documented by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

While, to my knowledge, it is not part of either standard, it is surely a reasonable assumption, particularly if you have compilers from the same suite or vendor.  For instance, G++ 4.3 simply uses the #defined values from `<limits>` in `<climits>`.