# What is the difference between <climits> and <limits> header files in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, limit, numeric-limits

Limits is the header file in c++ which consists of `numeric_limits` class whereas climits is the header file consisting of the min and max values of various data types only.

Limits can be used whereever one wants to use climits, however the opposite of this is not true.

Hence when is it advised to use climits and when limits?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "limits" and "climits"? Are you referring to the standard headers `<climits>` and `<limits.h>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalence of <limits> and <climits>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653150/equivalence-of-limits-and-climits)

Comment: @Angew No I am referring to the header files limits and climits in c++

Comment: @didiz That question talks about one specific case. I am looking for an answer which considers all cases and also is able to differentiate when to use when.

Answer (score 7):

`climits`/`limits.h` is part of the programming language C. If you are writing in C then you use that. C++ has this because it inherits the standard library from C.

`limits` serves the same purpose, but via a modernized C++ interface. If you are wrting C++, then always use this. There is no reason to use the C header.

Comment: So would you recommend to not use any of the <c types> header files when we are writing the code in modernized c++?

Comment: The wording of this answer is a bit ambiguous. The `<climits>` wrapper of `<limits.h>` is only available in C++, not C. Also it might be worth noting that in C++ those headers are not guaranteed to contain any declarations specified in the C standard unless explicitly specified in C++ standard.