# fatal error: 'limits' file not found #include <limits>

Tags: c++, linux, clang, llvm

I am making the test-suite of llvm.

```
[test-suite-build$ make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target fpcmp-target
[  0%] Built target fpcmp-target
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target timeit-target
[  0%] Built target timeit-target
[  0%] Built target build-litsupport
[  0%] Built target build-fpcmp
[  0%] Built target build-HashProgramOutput.sh
[  0%] Built target build-timeit
[  0%] Building CXX object Bitcode/Benchmarks/Halide/local_laplacian/CMakeFiles/halide_local_laplacian.dir/driver.cpp.o
In file included from /home/summer/llvm-16/test-suite/Bitcode/Benchmarks/Halide/local_laplacian/driver.cpp:1:
/home/summer/llvm-16/test-suite/Bitcode/Benchmarks/Halide/local_laplacian/../common/benchmark.h:4:10: fatal error: 'limits' file not found
#include <limits>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [Bitcode/Benchmarks/Halide/local_laplacian/CMakeFiles/halide_local_laplacian.dir/build.make:76: Bitcode/Benchmarks/Halide/local_laplacian/CMakeFiles/halide_local_laplacian.dir/driver.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14272: Bitcode/Benchmarks/Halide/local_laplacian/CMakeFiles/halide_local_laplacian.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

I found limits.h in /usr/linux/

And I reinstall these libraries:
gcc build-essential manpages-dev make perl
zlib1g zlib1g-dev
libssl-dev
linux-libc-dev

But doesn't work

Comment: You are trying to build C++ code with a C compiler. Use `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile C++ code in a typical (Ubuntu) linux, you need the "g++" package.

Comment: Or at least `libstdc++-dev`, which is likely a dependency of `g++`

Answer (score 1):

`"limits.h"` and and C++ `<limits>` are not the same thing.
[Equivalence of <limits> and <climits>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653150/equivalence-of-limits-and-climits)

Otherwise, you are probably missing C++ std libs.
[Clang doesn't see basic headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823/clang-doesnt-see-basic-headers)

To make sure, compile first with `-v` flag to see where is it looking for those headers, so you can verify yourself if they exist.

Make sure you have C++ headers installed (e.g. package name `libstdc++`).
Additionally make sure that you compile your C++ files with necessary flags (`-std=c++`, `-stdlib=libstdc++`).

Comment: If you're going to install `libc++-dev`, `-stdlib` needs to be `libc++`, not `libstdc++` (the latter is often the default).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are right! I just wrote the clang stdlib name, because I was thinking about clang compiler. Edited response to suggest using GCC lib as it is more commonly used on linux. Thanks for pointing it out!